# Use a random array of div in JavaScript with probability

Tags: javascript, random, probability

I try to do a script in JavaScript where I try to do a building with random wall, door, window and decoration (and random floors)

But I try to add a probabilty of :
more probability of door and probability of window not null on downstairs
more probability of window and probability of door not null on upstairs
I got the condition where upstairs and downstairs.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `pickItem` function I wrote in my code snippet. In this case, I have set it up so you pass in two arguments, one being an array of `items` (i.e your `items` array) and another being a `chance` array which you can create yourself. The `chance` array define the chances of each element in your `items` array of being picked. Take a look at the code snippet to see how I have created a `chance` array based off of my `letters` array.

If you observe the outputted result, you can see that the item 'a' from `letters` is usually picked 1/2 or more than 1/2 the time, as it has been given the chance of 50%

So, if you apply this logic to your `items` array, you will be able to make it so particular elements from `items` are picked more frequently than others.

```js
function rand(intMin, intMax) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (intMax - intMin + 1) + intMin);
}

let letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']; // dummy data, this is your items array

/* 
 a --> 50%
 b --> 20%
 c --> 10%
 d --> 5%
 e --> 10%
 f --> 5%
*/

// The following chances can be defined in an array like so:
//            a    b   c  d   e  f
let chance = [50, 20, 10, 5, 10, 5]; // chance as a percentage (%)

function pickItem(items, chance) { // Pick an item from the letters array as defined by the chance
  let randIndex = rand(0, items.length - 1); // pick a random letter index
  while (!(chance[randIndex] >= rand(1, 100))) { // If the chance of that letter being picked isnt met, then pick a new letter
    randIndex = rand(0, items.length - 1); // pick a new random letter index
  }

  return items[randIndex]; // return the letter when found
}

// To show the function working we can print a bunch of letters:
for (var i = 0; i < letters.length * 2; i++) { // Print out a picked item 12 times
  console.log(pickItem(letters, chance)); // At least 6 of these items (1/2 the time) should be 'a'
}
```